# "perf top" in Linux shows "Kernel address maps (/proc/{kallsyms,modules}) are restricted. "

Tags: linux-kernel, perf

Can't use `perf top` in our process, shows error:

```
Kernel address maps (/proc/{kallsyms,modules}) are restricted.
Check /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict.
Kernel samples will not be resolved.
```

It's definitely not because of linux kernel configuration, for other processes is ok for `perf top`

Is there any syscall or kernel API could affect the usage of `perf top`?

--------------------------------Update-----------------------------------

```
$dmesg
perf interrupt took too long (10016 > 9615), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 13000

$cat /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict
1
```